Unable to get data change notifications
Why we are unable to get data change when nodes get inactive and active again however it handle doesn't get change and also it is present in monitored items dictionary in asyncua?

Looks like a server fault. If a node gets removed there should be an update that the node is no longer available. Expanded the Subscriptionhandler class to get status_change_notification. Maybe there is a hint from the server that the node is removed.
class SubHandler:

    def datachange_notification(self, node: Node, val, data):
        ...

    def event_notification(self, event: ua.EventNotificationList):
        ...

    def status_change_notification(self, status: ua.StatusChangeNotification):
        _logger.info("status_notification %s", status)

